# Removing a Node in C

Tags: c

so I'm trying to write a method that deletes a node and all nodes attached to it, but I'm confused on what to do. I know the free method releases the memory used, and when I created the node, I used malloc. I'm unsure why free isn't removing the node and what should I do instead.

```
struct node {
        char *data;
        struct node *left;
        struct node *right;
}*child = NULL;

    void delete(node* root){
        char array[13];
        node *toDelete;
        //takes in name of node to be deleted
        //scan method to find the node to delete and deletes all of the children of the node first before deleting
        printf ("Please specify a name to delete\n");
        scanf("%s", array);
        toDelete = scan(root, array); //return which node to delete
        removeChild(&toDelete);  //helper method here to go through and delete each children
        if(toDelete == NULL) {
                printf("ERROR -- Node does not exist");
        }
}


void removeChild(node **trash){
        if((*trash)->left == NULL && (*trash)->right == NULL) { //no parents
                free(trash);
                *trash = NULL;
        }
        else if((*trash)->left == NULL && (*trash)->right != NULL) { //have mother
                removeChild((*trash)->right);
        }
        else if((*trash)->left != NULL && (*trash)->right == NULL) { //have father
                removeChild((*trash)->left);
        } else{  //have both
                removeChild((*trash)->left);
                removeChild((*trash)->right);
        }
}
```

Comment: You should check the return of `scanf` and limit the characters stored to `12`, e.g. `if (scanf ("%12s", array) != 1) { /* handle error */ }` and you should also remove any characters that remain in `stdin` (otherwise that will be taken as your next input)

Answer (score 4):

I didn't look thoroughly at your code, but I saw this which doesn't do what you think it does:

```
void removeChild(node * trash){
    if(trash->left == NULL && trash->right == NULL) { //no parents
            free(trash);
            trash = NULL;
    }
 ...
```

The last statement which intends to clear the pointer only does that for the parameter.  The caller's pointer (which is passed to `removeChild()`) does not have its pointer NULLed.  That is because parameters passed to a function are copied.  They are not passed by reference.

Presumably other code could depend on the pointer being cleared, and so this would not satisfy it.

Comment: In other words, if you are relying on the pointer passed as `node * trash` being `NULL` after `trash = NULL;`, only the copy of trash within `removeChild` is set to `NULL`, the pointer passed to `removeChild` in not effected in the caller. If you need this to work, you need to pass the address of the pointer from the caller, e.g. `&nodepointer` and change the parameter for `removeChild` to `node **trash` .

Comment: I changed my code accordingly and tried inputting in pointers where it made sense, but I'm getting some warnings still on the `removeChild` method. Is there something I'm not seeing?

Comment: @antelemon:  Take the warnings seriously and resolve them.  There is no reason this code should have any warnings even on the most picky setting of warnings.  Transforming pointer code like this is difficult to get right.  Probably you did not need to change all the pointer types to an extra level of indirection, only those needing indirect access through a function (`removeChild()`).

Comment: @antelemon:  Oh, I see:  You did update the function.  In `RemoveChild()`, the `free(trash)` should be `free(*trash)`.  I'll leave the reason why as an exercise for you to figure out.